# How to test a function which modify a mock member?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mocking

I have a problem with Mockito. I have two different class. My purpose is test “setChanges” function. this is my first class :

```
class M {
private String a;
private String b;
private boolean c = false;

public String getA() {
    return a;
} 
public void setA( String _a ) {
     a = _a;
} 
public String getC() {
    return c;
} 
public void setC( final boolean imp ) {
     c = imp;
}
```

}

this is the main class which has “setChanges” function:

```
class MyMainClass {
private String getMyA() {
    return "Data";
}

private static void setChanges(final M m) {
    if (getMyA().equals(m.getA())){
        m.setC(true);
    }
}
```

}

How can I test "setChanges"? Which means that if getA() returns "Data", How can I check getC() that should be "true"?

Comment: Is there a way of setting `a` in class `M`, such as a constructor or a setter method?  If so, you don't need Mockito for this.

Comment: Yes, there is a setter Method for a .it set by the user.

Comment: Then use it.  Make an `M` with `a` set to `"Data"` and another `M` with `a` set to `"Something else"`.  Call `setChanges` twice, and assert that the output in each case is the right thing.  No mocking required.

Comment: Also, your `MyMainClass` doesn't actually compile - you've got a static method calling a non-static one without specifying what instance to call it on.  You'll find 
 your code easier to test once you can get it to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, It works with this code :

```
@Test
```

public void testsetChanges(){

```
MyMainClass  mmc  = new MyMainClass ();
M m = new M();
m.setA("Data");

Method method = MyMainClass.class.getDeclaredMethod(
            "setChanges",
            M.class
    );
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(method, m );

assertTrue(m.getC());
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Pass in an instance of `M` which satisfies (or doesn't satisfy) `getMyA` and validate that `M#getC` returns `true` (or `false`, depending on what you're testing).  No mocks required.

Comment: I think it doesn't work because the "setChanges" is static void function.

Comment: It'll work just fine because you would only be able to test the instance of `M` passed to your method *anyway*.

Comment: @Test
public void testsetChanges(){
 
 MyMainClass  mmc  = new MyMainClass ();
 M m = new M();
 m.setA("Data");
 
 mmc.setChanges(m);
 
 assertTrue(m.getC());
}